# cp: `./lcommands/cde.pdf' and `lcommands/cde.pdf' are the same file

Tags: command-line, find

I am trying to learn about the `find` command. I would like to understand the meaning of this warning:

```
ankit@battlestar:/home/mount_150/studies$ find -iname "*.pdf" -exec cp -ar {} lcommands/  \;
cp: `./lcommands/june.pdf' and `lcommands/june.pdf' are the same file
cp: `./lcommands/cde.pdf' and `lcommands/cde.pdf' are the same file
cp: `./lcommands/abc.pdf' and `lcommands/abc.pdf' are the same file
ankit@battlestar:/home/mount_150/studies$ ls -l lcommands/
```

You can see here the procedure I followed and the directory structure:

[image]

Comment: I think, it says, It has found another instance of the same file. Because, `./lcommands` and `lcommands` are the same directory. The command executes in such a way that, it reads both `./lcommands` and `lcommands`.

Comment: but initially the destination folder is empty.

Comment: Yes but if you have the same file in two different folders of your source, eg.`source/bla/june.pdf` and `source/blubb/june.pdf` and try to copy both to `destination/`, with `cp -ar source/ destination/`, cp will give you an error, when it gets to `source/blubb/june.pfd`, since `destination/june.pdf` will already exist then from when you copied `source/bla/june.pdf` to `destination`.

Comment: it means that the find commands should also display all the files mentioned in the find pattern,but it is giving only the 3 files (1 copy each):-  ankit@battlestar:/home/mount_150/studies$ find  -iname "*.pdf"  
./june.pdf
./cde.pdf
./abc.pdf

Comment: @Con-f-use, i'm sorry i got your point just today. Thanks. So the find command will also search in lcommands and while it is trying to copy it already finds a copy there..  thanks again > :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

find command would also search in the lcommand directory for any instances of the pdf files. Since the files were copied the pdf files were copied to the directory; find came up with the warning.

Comment: `find` did not come up with the warnings, `cp` did.

Answer (score 2):

[Ankid's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/175668/250300) was accepted, but it is mostly wrong. Yes, find also searches the `lcommands` directory, but as you can see from the screenshot part before find, directory `lcommands` already contains the three pdf files before find command was issued.

What really happens: `find -exec cp` results in a command `cp ./lcommands/abc.pdf lcommands/`. As ./lcommands is exactly the `lcommands` directory (`./` is the same as `././`, the same as `./././././`, the same as the directory you are just in), it would result in copying `abc.pdf` over itself, which `cp` refuses, because that would result in a crippled destination file (at least for files bigger than `cp`'s buffer is long).

Imagine how `cp` works: it opens source file, reads a chunk, opens destination file (truncating it if it should exist and not be empty), writes the previous read chunk to destination file; then it would read the next chunk of source file, but anything except the first chunk is gone because of previous truncate operation. So authors of `cp` tried hard to detect any situation where the source and destination file are the same.

`cp` is not complaining, that the file is already there - it would happily overwrite it! Except you additionally used option `-i` or `-n`. So [jpic's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/171848/250300) is correct - even if it might not be very detailed and didn't help you therefore.

The same with the other two pdf files.

To make it as clear as possible: `cp` doesn't complain because the destination file(s) exist(s), but because it is (they are) exactly the source file(s). And this is exactly what the error message says.

Comment: “Directory `lcommands` already contains the three pdf files before find command was issued.” It did but they were later removed. See the `rm` command in the screenshot. Except that, your answer is correct.

Answer (score 1):

It is an **error** (return code 1), from **cp**:

```
>>> cp foo foo
cp: `foo' and `foo' are the same file
<<< 11:33.40 Sat Aug 04 2012!~ 
1
```

Which means that cp did not do anything.

Comment: actually cp did copy the files to lcommand folder; as you could see in the screen shot.